# Login and POST data to a webpage with a WinApp

Tags: c#, winforms, http

the company that I work for has a website to enter some user's code and get details of user.
The problem is I have to enter the codes one by one and this bothers me (very boring job!), so I want to make a win app to post batch data and get response. I have to login first to access the data entry page.
What scenario do you suggest to make this app?

Comment: Have you looked at solutions like AutoIt? http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: @rene I will take a deep look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post should help you with the login portion of the problem

[HTTP client and forms authentication in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640116/http-client-and-forms-authentication-in-c-sharp)