# how to dowloand file from https url with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download files via https but I am getting this error. Where am I making mistakes? I used c#(asp.net)

The error is" Additional information: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

```
        string uri = "https://myurl";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(uri, "localPathToSaveFile");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPS file download C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597127/https-file-download-c-sharp)