# authenticate Lightswitch Odata service that uses forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, odata, visual-studio-lightswitch

I created an OData service using VS Lightswitch with an endpoint like this:

http://mydevsite.com/lightswitchapps/mydata/products.svc

The service is secured with forms authentication. When I put the url into a browser I am asked for credentials.

I want to build a console app in C# to consume the service. But I can't find any examples of how to authenticate.

I've worked through this which consumes the Northwind service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868028%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

But I need help with the authentication.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in LightSwitch OData Service.

Here is the solution :

```
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:5487/ApplicationData.svc/");
    var container = new MyNameSpace.ApplicationData(uri);
    container.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: many thanks, this is what I ended up with but I forgot to come back and leave the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is similar to this one:
[HttpClient and forms authentication in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640116/httpclient-and-forms-authentication-in-c-sharp)
Please reference it.