# LightSwitch 2013: Calling the OData ApplicationData.svc service with forms authentication

Tags: rest, odata, forms-authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch, win-universal-app

I have written a simple LightSwitch 2013 application that manages "customers" by adding a customer entity and let LightSwitch handle the attached SQL Server file.
LightSwitch exposes the data with a **restful service (ApplicationData.svc)** that can be called like this:

```
https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationData.svc/Customers
```

Now, I want to add another **Windows 8 Universal App** client application (Store and Phone), aside to the "included" HTML and Silverlight Desktop client. Therefore, I need to call the restful service programatically.

I struggle there with the **forms authentication** that I have enabled. So I try to log in programatically by code. I do not exactly know what is going on, I tried to analyze the traffic on the wire with fiddler. I see that there is a "LogIn.aspx" page called (GET), then a postback with the credentials filled out by the user is made (POST).

I always get an "401 - unauthorized" response.

My best guess looks like this:

```c#
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://somesite.azurewebsites.net");

            // Get the login page
            var loginGet = client.GetAsync("/LogIn.aspx").Result;
            loginGet.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Post-back to login page with credentials
            var loginPost = client.PostAsync("/LogIn.aspx", new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "LoginUser$Username", "myname" },
                { "LoginUser$Password", "mypw"},
                { "LoginUser$LoginButton", "LOG+IN" },
            })).Result;
            loginPost.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // try to get the customers list via OData
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Getting a "401 - unauthorized" here:
            var response = client.GetAsync("ApplicationData.svc/Customers").Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
```

Could someone kick me into the right direction?

PS: 
I know that if I wrote an .NET client, I could just use the "Lightswitch.ApplicationData" class to call the restful service seamlessly. This solution is suggested here:

[authenticate Lightswitch Odata service that uses forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563839/authenticate-lightswitch-odata-service-that-uses-forms-authentication)

But in my case, I have a Windows 8 Universal App, so I cannot reference the "Server" assembly generated by LightSwitch, which is based on the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finaly found it .... I was completely wrong by handling around with cookies ....

A lightswitch OData service with Forms authentication is exposed with **Basic Authentication**.

```
https://usernamme:password@somesite.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationData/Customers
```

Be sure that you are using SSL of course!

See this article: [Exposing LightSwitch Application Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh674021.aspx)