# .NET https authentication (pingdom api)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have to receive the API from Pingdom. The address is https://api.pingdom.com

How can I in .NET do a http get when it is https? Google gives me nothing to work with :(

Best regards

UPDATE::

Thanks for help.. Trying with PowerShell:

```
$NC = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS")
$CC = New-Object System.Net.CredentialCache
$CC.Add("api.pingdom.com", 443, "Basic", $NC)


$webclient = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://api.pingdom.com")
$webclient.Credentials = $CC
$webclient.PreAuthenticate = $true
$webclient.Method = "POST"

$webclient.GetResponse()
```

I get the error: Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Any good advice?

Comment: there is an example .net app which uses the API, you can download the visual studio project here: http://www.pingdom.com/services/api-applications/

Answer (score 2):

Basically,

> http://www.pingdom.com/services/api-documentation-rest/
>
> The authentication method for user credentials is HTTP Basic Access Authentication (encrypted over HTTPS). This means you will provide your credentials every time you make a request. No sessions are used.

HTTP Basic Access Authentication is well documented both here and on MSDN.

This answer together with the API docs should get you started down the right path.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1127295/64976
>
> Assuming you use a WebRequest, you attach a CredentialCache to your request:

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add("www.site.com", 443, "Basic", nc);
```

The `CredentialCache` is used to be able to set Basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the credentials of the webclient and then any time a login is needed, it will supply what you gave it.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password", "Domain");
```