# C# How to login as a different user programmatically into a NTAuthenticated Website

Tags: c#, authentication, automation, nt

Our team uses a website that uses NT Authentication. I need to point my automation scripts to that site. 
This needs passing the credentials of the testuser accounts to the application and not mine.

How do I do that programmatically so that the application won't prompt for the credentials.

Alternatively, can somebody suggest a way to handle the  windows security prompt so that I can enter the username and password there and then?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You will want to impersonate in your calling C# app, then connect to the site with integrated windows auth.

Here is a tutorial on how to impersonate from a C# app to make a remote call:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called HttpWebRequest. Look at this answer, previously posted on SO: [Login to the page with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450380/login-to-the-page-with-httpwebrequest)

Comment: This is a different problem. The asker of this problem needs to do an integrated login to a website not using forms auth. The SO question you linked is about automating forms-based login, retreiving the auth cookie and resending with every request, etc.