# Writing a cookie locally

Tags: c#

I let my program (c#) log in to website, i get correct buffered cookie information. Yet, i get a 401, session timed out, when i want to retrieve the correct data behind my login.

So i figured, the website must not be able to retrieve that cookie info. Can't figure out how to store it so that the website can retrieve it.

```
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Gegevens);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
```

cookieHeader, contains the correct info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking how to add a cookie or why you're not getting it? Sorry for the mixup

Comment: If i need to information from cookieHeader, stored in a .txt locally for it to work, since i got it now there, and it doesn't seem working, or is there more too it?

Comment: Are you getting the 401 error from the code you posted, or is it coming from another `WebRequest` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: from another webrequest, i let my program log in to the website, i get a succes message, but when i try and get the next page, it gives me 401

Comment: Are you trying to login to the website using web request? This question will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450380/login-to-the-page-with-httpwebrequest  ... In the same answer you will also see how to retrieve the cookie..

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a `CookieContainer` to your web request and use this very same `CookieContainer` for the following requests, too.

See [MSDN for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx#MtViewDropDownText).

You could (if you want to persist the cookies upon closing your application) get the list of Cookies from the `CookieContainer` and serialize these. Upon opening the application you could deserialize and rebuild the `CookieContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment you provided, I'm going to hazard a guess and say you aren't properly adding your login cookies to your next `WebRequest`. Cookie handling with a `WebRequest` object is a bit difficult, so I recommend using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` which has built-in cookie parsing. You only have to change a couple lines of code here and there:

**Building a request** (using the same example in your question)

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

// When using HttpWebRequest or HttpWebResponse, you need to cast for it to work properly
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.CookieContainer = cookies;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Gegevens);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

// Cast here as well
using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    // Code related to the web response goes in here
}
```

Right now, your cookie information is saved in the `CookieContainer` object. It can be reused later in your code to validate your login. You don't need to write this cookie information to the disk if you don't need to.

**Building a request with cookie information**
(Pretty much the same as above, but you're not adding POST data and you're using a GET request)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.CookieContainer = cookies; // This is where you add your login cookies to the current request
req.Method = "GET";

using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    // Code related to the web response goes here
}
```

Hopefully this will get you on the right track :)